# Can't pass parameters in HTML onClick function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Me and my teammates have an issue we haven't been able to solve and hope someone can help us.

We have 4 images on the top and we want to change the content of another div when we click on them.

This is the code of the JavaScript function which puts the 4 upper images and works well. The problem appears when we try to pass parameters from the *onClick()* function to our *modificarDetailed()*. (Scroll to the right to see the most important part of *img*)

```
function insertRecommended(parent,events) {
    var hola = events[0].author;
    parent.append('<div class="row">\
            ...
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">\
                <img class="img-responsive img-portfolio img-hover" src="'+ events[1].image+'" alt="" onclick="modificarDetailed('+events[1].nameEvent+','+events[1].category+','+events[1].author+','+events[1].dateInit+','+events[1].image+');">\
        </div>\
        ...
    </div>')
}
```

This is the function which adds the HTML code of a **DetailedEvent**. As you can see, we try to make it dynamic and change the content of the *inputs*

```
function insertDetailedEvent(parent,event) {

    parent.append('<!-- Features Section -->\
        <div class="row" > \
            <form id="' + "detailedform" + '">\
            <div class="col-lg-12">\
                <h2 class="page-header"><input type="text" name="eventname" value="'+event.eventName+'"/></h2>\
            </div>\
           <div class="col-md-6">\
                <ul>\
                    <li><strong>Categoría: </strong><input type="text" name="category" value="'+event.category+'"/></li>\
                    <li><strong>Creador: </strong><input type="text" name="author" value="'+event.author+'"/></li>\
                    <li><strong>Fecha de Inicio: </strong><input type="text" name="dateInit" value="'+event.dateInit+'"/></li>\
                </ul>\
                <p>'+event.description+'</p>\
                </form>\
            </div>\
            <div class="col-md-4 .col-md-offset-4">\
                <img name="eventImage" class="img-responsive" src="'+event.image+'" alt="">\
            </div>\
        </div>\
        <!-- /.row -->')

}
```

After that, we have this to update the content of **DetailedEvent**

```
function init(parent){

    listEvent("logon",function(events){

        insertRecommended(parent,events);
        insertDetailedEvent(parent,events[0]);

    },function(){},function(){});
}

function modificarDetailed(eventName,category,author,dateInit,image){
    var documento= $("#detailedform");
    documento.find('input[name="eventname"]').val(eventName);
    documento.find('input[name="category"]').val(category);
    documento.find('input[name="author"]').val(author);
    documento.find('input[name="dateInit"]').val(dateInit);
    //documento.find('img[name="eventImage"]').src(image);

}
```

And this is how we call the init in the html main document

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            init($('#Content'));

        });
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you creating multiple elements with `id="detailedForm"`? IDs have to be unique.

Comment: I think it's the `event` thing: `function insertDetailedEvent(parent,event)`. It is reserved.

Comment: @Barmar technically we are overwritting it. But thank you both for your responses! We finally found the solution, I'm going to post it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally we found the solution. We saw it yesterday searching on the net but we did it wrong so it didn't work at first.

It is necessary to use **'\'**, so this is how it was:

```
<img class="img-responsive img-portfolio img-hover" src="'+ events[1].image+'" alt="" onclick="modificarDetailed('+events[1].nameEvent+','+events[1].category+','+events[1].author+','+events[1].dateInit+','+events[1].image+');">\
```

And this is how it must be done:

```
<img class="img-responsive img-portfolio img-hover" src="'+ events[1].image+'" alt="" onclick="modificarDetailed(\''+events[1].nameEvent+'\',\''+events[1].category+'\',\''+events[1].author+'\',\''+events[1].dateInit+'\',\''+events[1].image+'\',\''+events[1].description+'\');">
```

Thanks anyway to @Barmar and @yak613 for their try.